# Eclipse auto-formatting of multiline // (double-slash) comments

Tags: eclipse

Right now, Eclipse autoformats

```
// An example of a two line comment.
```

to

```
// An example of a two line
// comment.
```

When I edit it to

```
// An alternative example of a two line
// comment.
```

the autoformatter does this:

```
// An alternative example of a two
// line
// comment.
```

Is it possible to somehow fix this in the autoformatter settings?

Answer (score 0):

ie. for JAVA try in

```
Preferences->Java->formatter
```

there click on Edit. In 'Line Wrapping' tab you can set line wrapping how you like

you have to change name of the Profile before you apply changes

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found anything there that would fix it... it's probably a bug in the autoformatter.

Comment: sorry my mistake, for comments there is another tab 'Comments' (next one) and there you have at the bottom Line width

Answer (score 0):

You should probably increase size of your line. Preferences -> number of characters in line. By default it's 80. but probably you got less, so that's the result.

Comment: I have 100, the example in my question was just for illustration ;)

Comment: then see answer by @Mateusz, as this seems to be a problem with java code formatter. It controls everything related to java code editing, including comments. You'll need to copy current default formatter, as it's impossible to edit it end then in it find a sections that relates to comments and hopefully there you'll find something about comment line lenght.